# Excel: Using to columns to find the max value in a 3rd column

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of data with 3 columns, the first has a persons name, the second has the type of report it was, and the third has how long it took for the report to be submitted. I want to look up the largest time, for each person for each type of report.

This is what I was trying but it just always gives me "none". Any ideas?

=IF(AND(Jan!$B$2:$B$115="Bill W",Jan!$C$2:$C$115="Report 1"),MAX(Jan!$F$2:$F$115),"none")

Answer (score 1):

"I want to look up the largest time, for each person for each type of report. "

If you just want to look up the largest time then you may use the "max" function from Home tab of the Ribbon.

1. Select the Entire column(make sure that the last one is empty).
2. click "max" function under "autosum" in the Ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Try Pivoting:
[Excel Pivot Tables Tutorial : What is a Pivot Table and How to Make one](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/08/19/excel-pivot-tables-tutorial/)

Or if you need to use formula, then paste following formula to `D2`, press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER as it is an array formula. Then drag down to copy:

`=MAX(IF(($A$2:$A$11=A2)*($B$2:$B$11=B2),$C$2:$C$11))`

[image]